# Is it possible to trigger a virtual pageview on a site tracking stats with awstats?

Tags: analytics, tracking, awstats

What I'm Doing
I have a multi-step form (7 steps) where users make a choice on each form part and submit them on the 7th part of the form. It's a contest entry form.

The problem
There is only one pageview generated when the user clicks through each part of the form.

What I'd like to see
I'd like to trigger a pageview (not a page reload) each time a user clicks the next or previous button to go the next part of the form. I know you can do this with Google Analytics, using Tags and such. But my client is using AWstats. I am curious if it is possible to create this scenario while using AWstats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWStats reports on your server's access log. So unless there is an external request to your server (ie. a page reload, that doesn't hit the browser cache) then no pageview is going to be recorded.

It sounds as if the 7 steps of your form are all on the same page, perhaps implemented with client-side JavaScript? In this case there is no request to your server and no "pageview" recorded.

If your 7 steps where on 7 separate pages (perhaps a `?page=N` query string) and each step was submitted to the server as you progressed then you would expect this to appear in your access log.

A workaround would be to issue an XMLHttpRequest (AJAX) request to your server on each step. Since this is an external request to your server it should appear in your access log and be reported by AWStats. You can also make this request unique so you can differentiate it from normal page loads.

Comment: Thanks for this. I think what I'm going to do is use jquery and ajax to load a page into a hidden div. That will count as a pageload, or at least something awstats should recognize as a view.

Comment: You don't even need the "into a hidden div" part. You could just make a request in the background and discard the response?

Comment: Thanks for the input here. I ended up using a quick bit of jQuery to load files, still, to a hidden div, although, you're right, it's unnecessary. Here's what I put together:https://gist.github.com/digisavvy/585d3bdbfcd7b0aa5a09

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty, thanks again for the help. This gist is what set me up to complete what I needed: https://gist.github.com/digisavvy/585d3bdbfcd7b0aa5a09 - The suggestion to leverage Ajax helped a lot, too. =)

Thanks again.